# *expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'* warning in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am getting warning message like : **expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'**
Below is my code:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_DL_SLOWA 30


void  szyfr(char oryginalne[MAX_DL_SLOWA], int* dlugosc, int zaszyfrowane[MAX_DL_SLOWA+1]) {
     int  i, j;
     *dlugosc = strlen(oryginalne);
     for (i = 0; i < *dlugosc; i++) {
       if (i < *dlugosc-1){
                j = i + 1;
       }else{
            j = i + 1 - *dlugosc;
       }
       zaszyfrowane[i] = (int)oryginalne[j] - (int)'a';
     }
}

void main(){

    char slowo[MAX_DL_SLOWA];
    int* dlugosc;
    int kod[MAX_DL_SLOWA+1],i;

    //Wczytanie i szyfrowanie
    printf("Podaj slowo: ");
    scanf("%s",&slowo);
    printf("\nTwoje slowo: %s",slowo);
    szyfr(slowo, &dlugosc, kod);
    printf("\nTwoj kod: %s",kod);   
}
```

I am getting this validation line where I am calling *szyfr* method with &*dlugosc* as an arg .
Anyone has any idea how could i change that to make it works without warnings?

Comment: `int* dlugosc;` --> `int dlugosc;`

Comment: You could not pass an 'int **' argument where an 'int *` is expected?

Comment: The warning seems pretty clearly worded. It would be good if you could explain what part of the warning you don't understand.

Comment: @kaylum thanks for your answer.I am totally new to C and these are my first steps with this language. I dont know why he is getting int ** if dlugosc is defined as int *. I can compile this code but want to understand those warnings..

Comment: `dlugosc` is an `int *`. But you are passing `&dlugosc` which is `int **`. But you are very right to heed the warnings. Your code is not correct and the compiler is giving you good indicators of where it is wrong.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&slowo);` should generate a warning, too. You pass a wrong pointer type (`char (*)[]` instead of `char *`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

> int* dlugosc;

to:

> int dlugosc;

In the original code, dlugosc is being declared as a pointer to an integer.  By using the '&' when szyfr() is called, you are passing the address of the pointer to the integer (IE an int**) instead of the pointer to the integer.  By changing the declaration of dlugosc to an int, you are able to reference its address using '&'.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code and it's working

```
void main(){

char slowo[MAX_DL_SLOWA];
int* dlugosc;
int kod[MAX_DL_SLOWA+1],i;

//Wczytanie i szyfrowanie
printf("Podaj slowo: ");
scanf("%s",&slowo[0]);
printf("\nTwoje slowo: %s",slowo);
szyfr(slowo, &dlugosc[0], kod);
printf("\nTwoj kod: %s",kod);   
}
```